# Can't Dismiss Keyboard in Ionic 5 on Android and iOS Devices

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, keyboard

Hello I'm trying to dismiss / hide the keyboard on iOS and Android devices using the Ionic 5 platform / Angular.

I've tried using `keydown.enter` and `keyup.enter` and `keypress` with no luck. While it might dismiss correctly on one device.

For example if I use `keydown.enter` to hide the keyboard.

iOS

- This works if there is text in the input that has focus. But if there is no text in the input it doesn't dismiss.

Android

- This works if there is NO text in the input that has focus. But if there IS text in the input it doesn't work.

```html
<ion-searchbar #searchBar 
  autocomplete="on" 
  inputmode="search" 
  showCancelButton="never" 
  debounce="500" type="text" 
  placeholder="{{searchPlaceholder}}" 
  [(ngModel)]="search"
  (ionChange)="handleSearchInput($event)" 
  (keydown.enter)="handleKeyPress($event)"
>
</ion-searchbar>
```

I've also tried `window:keydown` which causes really weird issues and randomly brings the keyboard up when I click on the UI.

This seems like a really common scenario. Not sure why it's proving so challenging.

Answer (score -2):

Why do you want to close the keyboard on key press?

If this has to be done try this: on keypress event on the input field / window, focus on some other element like a button or text which will automatically close the keyboard.

Please consider accessibility related issues too with this.